# Xamarin forms connect to local MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to read data from MSSQL database in my Xamarin forms app. Eventhough I have followed many tutorials on youtube , stackoverflow etc. I am not able to read the data from database because an error appears every time I try to run the app. Error example:

> "System.Exception: 'Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.'"

All I am using is `System.Data.SqlClient`, then I define in MainPage.xaml.cs connection string (to local DB), create new `SqlConnection` and then open the `SqlConnection`:

I have already tried to restart server, modify settings of TCP/IP and even turn off the firewall, as I found in internet tutorials, but nothing helped so far.. In my opinion the connection string should be correct, since I am able to connect to the database in Windows forms using the same procedure.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-....\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EFDB;User ID=MyUserID; Password =*******";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();
```

Comment: First, don't do this.  It's a horrible security risk.  Second, if you absolutely insist on doing it, your mobile device has no idea how to resolve this: "LAPTOP-..."

Comment: Try this connection string. "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=EFDB; User ID=MyUserID; Password =*******"; OR try to using the IP address rather than the desktop name, sometimes it cannot

Comment: The SQL Browser service needs to be running and accessible via UDP port 1433. Is the service enabled? Is it running? Is it accessible via UDP port 1433? (i.e.: is it blocked by Windows Firewall or similar?) Because there can be multiple instances of SQL Server running on a given machine the SQL Browser service supports the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to take an instance name (e.g.: `SQLEXPRESS`) and map it to the TCP port number that the related SQL Server service is listening on, after which the SQL client can connect to that port to perform SQL operations.

Comment: If you know which TCP port number a given SQL Server instance is listening on (check in the SQL Server [version] Configuration Manager) you don't even need the SQL Browser service, just use the port number in the connection string, e.g.: `Server=YourServerNameOrIpAddress,portNumber;`

Comment: Thank you for you help. For the conclusion to others who will struggle with this error: As @Jason wrote, mobile has no idea what "LAPTOP..." means. I found out that the emulated android device has its own IP address, which makes sense. Thus, it was required to enter the IP address instead of "local" or just "LAPTOP...".